# Load webView and do network request concurrently

Tags: ios, networking, webview, afnetworking

I have a UIWebView, and i found that i can not use AFNetworking to do a network request while the UIWebView is loading. The network request will only have responsed after the UIWebView is finishing loading.

So, is there a way to load a WebView and do a network request concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import <AFNetworking/UIWebView+AFNetworking.h>

[self.webView loadRequest:r
            progress:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite){}
            uccess:^NSString *(NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSString *HTML){}
            failure:^(NSError *error){}
 ];
```

instead of

```
 [self.webView loadRequest:r];
```